# BeagleBone Black won't power up from USB

Tags: power-supply, usb, beaglebone-black

I have been successfully using BBB powered from the USB adapter until now.

I had to do some restart, and then the board won't power up (the `PWR` led blinks once when I press the `POWER` button, then it stays like that, off).

Now I can only start the board using an external power supply (`5.0V`), and it seems that the board uses around ~`0.8A` and up to ~`1.1A`.

What can be wrong?

Why it isn't working now?

*L.E.* Also, I have noticed that the main chip (`AM355`) gets very hot, I can't put my finger more than one second on it.

*L.E.2.* I don't have attached any relevant power-consuming devices to it, only a USB WiFi dongle.

*L.E.3.* Before restarting the board, I was trying to get a `GPIO` pin working, the problem was that from the library I've used (`BlackLib`) when I set one `GPIO` pin to `high`, it would only stay `high` for around `10ms`, and then go `low` again. So for solving what, I have used [this](http://derekmolloy.ie/gpios-on-the-beaglebone-black-using-device-tree-overlays/) tutorial. I only got to the part where I exported some pins to the **/sys/class/gpio/export** file, and then echoing `1`s and `0`s to the associated pin (with a LED connected it didn't work), then I rebooted the board and this problem started.

I don't see any hardware mistakes that I may have done, is it possible that this fault is software-related?

Comment: Unplug the wifi dongle and see what happens.

Comment: @JRE Nothing happens, the problem persists.

Comment: OK.  Then at least you now know that the wifi dongle isn't source of the problem.

Comment: Then sounds like the chip is on the way to its ancestors.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev What do you mean by that?

Comment: It's going to die soon.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev Why? Do you recognize this behavior?

Comment: Not with BBB specifically. Something has short-circuited inside the chip, drawing the extra current. With time, the chip gets more damage from constant overheating and stops working completely. Have you been playing with GPIO lately, connecting something that didn't work as you expected?

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev Yep, I have been trying to get a GPIO pin working for output. But how can this be the problem?

Comment: If you killed a GPIO pin, it can cause a short inside the processor.  This would consume more current, hence the overheating.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev Killed in what way? I'm still able to use that pin.

Comment: 1A for BBB is too much... There is definitely some kind of short in your board.

Comment: @MariusMarusanici "I'm still able to use that pin" - That's something you should detail in your question: what you were doing before the incident, any hardware/software detail you think might be relevant etc.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev I updated the question.

Comment: @MariusMarusanici Did you by chance connect that LED without any resistor in series? When something as simple as a LED doesn't work, it usually means a basic mistake was made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Part of the chip on your board is damaged, probably the GPIO pin you were playing with, but not necessarily. Maybe you shorted a pin next to it, or damaged an internal buffer - such issues are almost impossible to diagnose precisely. Here are the options you have:

- Get a new board. Preferable if money is not a problem, and you need to trust your BBB. Using a damaged board in your projects will make them harder to debug, since you won't be sure whenever a bug is due to your HW or SW, or to the chip fault.
- Try to disable the pin. If you can reprogram the pin you suspect in a state which stops the overheating, you'll substantially prolong your BBB's life. Try to output 0, 1, configure it as input and see if the excessive current draw stops. Then apply that config on each reboot.
- Live with it. Since the chip is getting hot, it may not last very long, but you never know.